# How to specify current user desktop for DoCmd.TransferText

Tags: ms-access

This is what I have:

```
Private Sub EthosRpt_Click()

    DoCmd.OpenQuery "EthosSessions"

    DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "EthosSessions", "C:\Users\JDoe\Desktop\EthosRpt.csv", True

End Sub
```

It works with my user account (where my user account = JDoe). How do I get it to work for ANY current user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
Private Sub EthosRpt_Click()

    Dim FileName As String

    DoCmd.OpenQuery "EthosSessions"

    FileName =  Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\EthosRpt.csv"
    DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "EthosSessions", FileName, True

End Sub
```

Comment: This seems like the right solution, but I get an error saying I can't use an action query (which the query is) as a row source.

Comment: Ding, ding, ding! We have a winner. I just had to change the "EthosSessions" in the last line to the name of the resultant table.
(EthosSessions is a MakeTable Query)

Answer (score 1):

try "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\EthosRpt.csv"

like:
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "EthosSessions", "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\EthosRpt.csv", True

Answer (score 0):

first get the username as string and replace the username

```
Dim strDisplayName as string
Set objAD = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & objAD.UserName)
strDisplayName = objUser.DisplayName
```

than

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , 
"EthosSessions","C:\Users\" & strDisplayName & "\Desktop\EthosRpt.csv", True
```

Comment: That one pulls the username off the system login (CAC card) but the filing system is different. Like, That pulls "Jonathon Q Doe" as the Username when the profile in the file system is "JDoe."