# inserr User name into path to Desktp

Tags: ms-access, vba

Have this bit of code and I want to get the user name from environ and insert it into the path to the desktop in the code;

```
UseName = Environ("UserName")
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
acExport, _
acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
"RevbyYrbyMo", _
"C:\Users\UseName\Desktop\RSExcel.xlsx", _
True
```

Tried ampersands, quotes etc, nothing works. Want the spreadsheet to be on the desktop of the user automatically.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify current user desktop for DoCmd.TransferText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50595765/how-to-specify-current-user-desktop-for-docmd-transfertext)

Comment: Try: `DesktopPath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really looks to me like you've just not got the right combination of quotes and ampersands...

Try:

```
UseName = Environ("UserName")
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
acExport, _
acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
"RevbyYrbyMo", _
"C:\Users\" & UseName & "\Desktop\RSExcel.xlsx", _
True
```

Alternatively you could specify the whole name and path as that variable, something like:

```
FileName = "C:\Users\" & Environ("UserName") & "\Desktop\RSExcel.xlsx"
```

You can take that idea as far as you like - often a good way to deal with this sort of thing to make it really nice and clear is to turn every element of the method into a variable:

```
Dim TransferType As AcDataTransferType
Dim SpreadsheetType As AcSpreadSheetType
Dim TableName As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim HasFieldNames As Boolean

TransferType = acExport
SpreadsheetType = acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml
TableName = "RevbyYrbyMo"
FileName = "C:\Users\" & Environ("UserName") & "\Desktop\RSExcel.xlsx"
HasFieldNames = True

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet TransferType, SpreadsheetType, TableName, FileName, HasFieldNames
```

Also means it's really clear for later revision, troubleshooting or extension.

Comment: Well answered.  Really liked the last suggestion. Everything working as it should, so thank you for the explanation.  Appreciate the time you took. Thanks again.